# penalty in multitrip vrp if different vehicle visits a destination in 2nd trip ORTOOLS

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I have implemented multitrip (Allow vehicles to visit a destination more than once) VRP using ortools. This has been done by duplicating nodes for destinations and introducing virtual depots with negative loads.

I want same vehicle to visit destinations in 2nd trip which visited that destination in 1st trip. This is a soft constraint and a penalty should be added in the objective function if not followed. How can we implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  /// Adds a soft constraint to force a set of variable indices to be on the
  /// same vehicle. If all nodes are not on the same vehicle, each extra vehicle
  /// used adds 'cost' to the cost function.
  void AddSoftSameVehicleConstraint(const std::vector<int64_t>& indices,
                                    int64_t cost);
```

[Reference](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/8cea0ef3b9e8296d866c61453697253b043a60a1/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L842-L846)

Using this, I think you can model your requirement.